# Converting C# regex to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

I am converting my C# program to JavaScript for a Google Chrome extension.

Here is the C# regex:

```
Did you mean: </span><a href=/search.[a-zA-Z0-9=&;_-]{1,}q=[a-zA-Z0-9+-]{1,}
```

How can I match the same thing in JavaScript? The same regex doesn't work.

Edit:

The input String is:

```
>Did you mean: </span><a href=/search?hl=en&amp;safe=off&amp;&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=hD9PTYKpKcKtgQei4pUP&amp;ved=0CBIQBSgA&amp;q=Linkin+Park-In+The+End&amp;spell=1class=spell>Linkin Park-In
```

I need to match:

```
Did you mean: </span><a href=/search?hl=en&amp;safe=off&amp;&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=hD9PTYKpKcKtgQei4pUP&amp;ved=0CBIQBSgA&amp;q=Linkin+Park-In+The+End
```

Note: Quotes have been filtered out

Comment: Which part is the _actual_ regex object? Is it `/.[a-zA-Z0-9=&;_-]{1,}q=[a-zA-Z0-9+-]{1,}/` ?

Comment: Yes, I was wondering why google added those when I created the regex.

Comment: So what's the regular expression then? Just the URL matching or the whole string? Why don't you amend your question so will be able to provide proper answers... And what does Google have anything to do with it?

Comment: You could maybe provide some strings that should be matched by the regular expression.

Comment: Ok, I just added an edit. Also, I am running this search through google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this one in Javascript if it works what it should?

```
var rx = /Did you mean: <\/span><a href=["']?\/search.[a-zA-Z0-9=&;_-]+q=[a-zA-Z0-9+-]+/;
```

I may have escaped a few characters too many, but I've also changed the `{1,}` which are basically equivalent to `+` and I've added the quotation mark checking that may be present after `href`. Single or double quote.

If I execute this in Firebug on this stackoverflow page:

```
var rx = /Did you mean: <\/span><a href=["']?\/search.[a-zA-Z0-9=&;_-]+q=([a-zA-Z0-9+-]+)/;
rx.exec($(document.body).text());
```

It does find the whole text and since I've captured `q` variable as well it also displays *Linkin+Park*...

Comment: @Matt Ball: I don't think I know what you mean? The last slash is a forward slash which ends the regular expression. And a semi-colon to end the sentence of variable declaration.

Comment: Did not match it correctly, but it lead me to the right answer. Thanks.